# PyCharm - How to create a Run/Debug Configuration that executes a .bat file which uses a Python script as a parameter?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, monkeyrunner, monkey

I want to create a new Run/Debug Configuration which executes a `.bat` file that accepts a Python script as a parameter.

The program I want to execute is `MonkeyRunner` (a tool part of Android SDK) which is located in the `C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin` folder. And my PyCharm project is located in `C:\Users\talha\Documents\PyCharmProjects` folder.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is going to be pyhton shim that calls the bat file with whatever argument is being passed to it.

Comment: Is it has to be a Run/Debug Configuration? Maybe [External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) will do? But if it has to be a Run/Debug Configuration ... have a look at [CMD Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5834-cmd-support) and see if it can do that. Other than that .. maybe you can run it using some another way (e.g. create a task in your task runner that IDE supports -- e.g. Npm/Gulp/Grunt/etc)

Comment: 'External tools' utility does the work. If you post this comment as an answer, I will be able to accept as the answer of the question. Thanks. @LazyOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [free plugin on the JetBrains marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/265-batch-scripts-support) that provides:

> Windows Batch Scripts support for IntelliJ IDEA. Supports syntax
> highlighting, run configurations that can run any command, also empty
> configurations. Empty run configurations are useful when you want to
> execute an external tool through a run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually navigating in Explorer -- just use "Navigate | Select in... | Explorer (Alt+F1, 8)" on such bat file and IDE will open Explorer with that file already selected 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207057025-Can-I-run-a-batch-file-bat-from-within-the-IDE-